# Denoising created weird glowing artifacts on character

Tags: rendering, denoise

Whenever I try to render an image with my girl character, a weird glare is created at the end, when it denoises. Any idea why?

Thanks[image]

Comment: I think this is not denoising, but something in the compositor, since compositing also happens at the end of rendering. Did you check that?

Comment: Did you disable _Denoising_ to secure it is caused by that? Could you post a screenshot from the _Compositor_?

Comment: ...the only way I could imagine this is caused by denoising would be that there is something very bright causing fireflies and the denoiser blurs them all somehow instead of extinguishing them. But that's also something you can check better if you disable _Denoising_.